# PHPUnit: How do I obtain the ORIGINAL exception that causes a PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Warning

Tags: php, exception, phpunit

I'm writing a PHPUnit test (v4.6.7) for a new PHP class (v5.3.3) that does stuff with XML. The purpose of the test is to confirm that the class throws an DOMException when handed bad XML.

I want to collect the exception and perform an `assertInstanceOf` on it, comparing it to `DOMException`.

No matter what I do, by the time I can see the exception phpunit has already transformed the original exception into an instance of `PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Warning`.

For example, here is one effort in the code under test:

```
//...
try {
    $this->code_that_causes_exception();
} catch (\Exception $exception) {
    $className = get_class($exception);
    throw $exception;
}
//...
```

When run from within phpunit, the string stored in $className is `PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Warning`, as opposed to whatever exception the `code_that_causes_exception` actually raised.

*Begin Update*

Just to clarify my question, with no try/catch around the code under test, the message reported by phpunit is `DOMDocument::loadXML(): Start tag expected, '<' not found in Entity, line: 1`. I make the perhaps rash assumption that DOMDocument is throwing some sort of exception to produce this message. The DOMDocument says that DOMException is the parent of exceptions thrown from DOMDocument objects.

*End Update*

I want the original exception so that I can wrap the code under test with an appropriate try/catch to gracefully handle this failure situation.
How do I obtain the **original** exception from which the `PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Warning` was instantiated?

Answer (score 3):

#### Why this is happening

Your exception **is not converted** to a `PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Warning`, it is **never thrown**. PHPUnit automatically converts **PHP Warnings into exceptions**. This is enabled by the `convertWarningsToExceptions` property in the XML configuration file (there are also `convertNoticesToExceptions` and `convertErrorsToExceptions` respectively). All these settings are `true` by default.

This means that your original exception is probably never thrown, because a PHP warning is triggered before and then converted into an (instantly-thrown) exception by PHPUnit's error handler.

**Have a closer look at your caught exception to see which statement in your code triggers the PHP warning** (simply remove the `try`/`catch` statement to let PHPUnit present the error).

You can disable this behaviour in your `phpunit.xml` file:

```
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/4.6/phpunit.xsd"
     ...
     convertErrorsToExceptions="false"
     convertNoticesToExceptions="false"
     convertWarningsToExceptions="false"
     ...
```

#### How you *should* test exceptions

The probably easiest way to assert that a specific exception is thrown is to use the `@expectedException` annotation. This is discussed [in-depth in the manual](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.exceptions). Using this annotation saves you a lof of boilerplate code:

```
/**
 * @expectedException DOMException
 * @test
 */
public function myTestCase() {
    $this->code_that_causes_exception();
}
```

This test will **pass when a `DOMException` is thrown** and fail when no exception is thrown at all (or any other Exception is thrown).

Comment: This is helpful.

My purpose in running this test was to discover what exception, warning, or notice was actually happening in the real code. The "message", as reported by phpunit in the PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Warning, was `DOMDocument::loadXML(): Start tag expected, '<' not found in Entity, line: 1`.

My coding task was to extend the code under test to recognize and properly handle this case. I therefore want an easy way to see whatever php behavior provokes it.